# Decoding a JSON text file in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a text file where each line is a different JSON array with the same set of keys but different values in each line.  Each line is formatted like so:

```
{"Key A":"Value A1","Key B":"Value B1","Key C":"Value C1, Value C2, Value C3"}
```

I want to pull the values of one key and the first 4 values of another key and export to a csv file.

I want the output to look like this:

```
Value A1      ["Value C1", "Value C2", "Value C3"]
Value A12      ["Value C12", "Value C22", "Value C32"]
```

So far, I've split the file into multiple lines like this:

```
import json
import csv

jsonmov = []
with open('step3_desired_output.txt') as step3:
    for line in step3:
        jsonmov.append(json.loads(line))


print jsonmov{u'Title',[u'Actors'[0:3]]}  #print each line from jsonmov's title and 4 actors
```

This gives me an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Another syntax for the print line:

```
print jsonmov(u'Title',u'Actors')
```

gives the error

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable:
```

Any ideas on how to produce the csv file in the right format?

Comment: When you call `json.loads(line)` you end up with dictionaries.  Attempting to call `json.loads(jsonmov)` is redundant and causes errors.  You already have a list of dictionaries.

Comment: sorry, that line was a mistake and i've updated my question...Without that line in place...I get the errors I mentioned

Comment: Your sample code is still wrong - list indexing is done using square brackets and numbers:  `jsonmov[0]` -> first dictionary in your list.

Comment: @kegewe What is `jsonmov{...}` supposed to mean (with the curly braces)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
import csv

INPUT  = 'step3_desired_output.txt'
OUTPUT = 'my.csv'
MAXACTORS = 3

with open(OUTPUT, 'wb') as outf:
    outcsv = csv.writer(outf)
    with open(INPUT) as inf:
        for line in inf:
            mv = json.loads(line)
            title  = mv['Title']
            actors = mv['Actors'].split(', ', MAXACTORS)
            outcsv.writerow([title] + actors[:MAXACTORS])
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
import json
import csv

with open('/tmp/test.json') as f, open('/tmp/jout.csv', 'w') as fout:
    writer=csv.writer(fout)
    for line in f:
        jline=json.loads(line)
        print jline[u'Key A']+'\t['+jline[u'Key C']+']'
        # Value A1  [Value C1, Value C2, Value C3]
        # write to writer...
```

---

**Edit**

Perhaps:

```
import json

with open('/tmp/test.json') as f, open('/tmp/jout.csv', 'w') as fout:
    for line in f:
        data=[]
        jline=json.loads(line)
        print jline[u'Key A']+'\t['+', '.join('"{}"'.format(e.strip()) for e in jline[u'Key C'].split(','))+']'
        # Value A1  ["Value C1", "Value C2", "Value C3"]
        # add '\n' if you print to a file...
```

Comment: Actually, I'm curious if there is a way to get quotes around the actors names?

Comment: Add a `\n` to the end of the line then... The `\n` is automatic when output to the terminal, not automatic when output to a file.

Comment: And also, how to get each line from the json file to output onto a separate line